# Finding relevant products using multiple keywords

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to use the Amazon Product Advertising API to find relevant products.
I am searching using multiple keywords and am hoping to receive relevant results based on those keywords. The keywords can be random and at times not related at all to each other, so I want to find results that match the max number of keywords possible.

For example if I were to search using the keywords, 'Cat Figure Toys Kite Sim' I would hope to receive (at least) [this result](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00362MMBO) back, because it matches 3 of 5 keywords. At the moment for this search, no results are returned.

To make that search here is an example URL as displayed in the Scratchpad:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemSearch&SubscriptionId=XXX&AssociateTag=XXX&SearchIndex=All&Keywords=Cat%20Figure%20Toys%20Kite%20Sim&ResponseGroup=Images,ItemAttributes,Offers
```

(Subscription ID and Associate Tag commented out).

Are the power search terms that I am not aware of that would make this request work?